# Reuse jax-ws client proxies for different addresses

Tags: spring, web-services, jax-ws, cxf

I have a bunch of web services servers (around 200) running on the same machine which expose the same service on different ports.
I have a client which perform tasks which include calling the service on different servers.
Something like:

```
while (true) {
    task = readTask();
    runHelloService(task.serverAddress)
}
```

I was wondering what is the best way to generate the HelloService client proxy.
Can I generate one and replace the target address before each call?
Should i generate a client per server (which means 200 client proxies) and use the relevant one?
I will probably want to run the above loop concurrently on several threads.
Currently I have only one proxy which is generated by spring and cxf with the jaxws:client declaration.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting use case. I believe that changing the endpoint whilst sharing the proxy amongst multiple threads will not work. There is a one-to-one relationship between a client proxy and a conduit definition. [Changes to a conduit are explicitly not thread safe](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-AreJAX-WSclientproxiesthreadsafe?).

I recommend eschewing Spring configuration altogether to create client proxies and instead use programmatic construction of the 200 client proxies.

See also [Custom CXF Transport](http://cxf.apache.org/custom-cxf-transport.html) - **Simplified Client Workflow**.